# How do I conditionally delete an object in an array based on multiple object properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React context, I'm trying to render a few objects with a structure like this:

```
const regions = [
  {
    displayName: 'NYC',
    locations: [
      {name: 'thing', isVisible: false},
      {name: 'thing1', isVisible: false},
      {name: 'thing3', isVisible: false},
    ],
  }, 
  {
    displayName: 'Seattle',
    locations: [
      {name: 'thing', isVisible: true},
      {name: 'thing1', isVisible: true},
      {name: 'thing3', isVisible: true},
    ],
    ....
  },
  ....
];
```

My question is for the context of the first object with all `isVisible: false`, is it possible to delete the whole object if all the `isVisible` values are false? Basically using the example, this object:

```
{
  displayName: 'NYC',
  locations: [
    {name: 'thing', isVisible: false},
    {name: 'thing1', isVisible: false},
    {name: 'thing3', isVisible: false},
  ],
},
```

would be deleted.

If so, how? If not, is this achievable? Are there any alternate solutions?

Comment: use filter function in array

Comment: what do you mean by whole object?

Comment: Edited example in post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy with array filtering

```
// filter only returns regions where the internal function evaluates to true
regions.filter(function(region){
    // some returns true if at least one of the elements in the array causes the function below to return true
    return region.locations.some(function(location){
        return location.isVisible
    })
})
```

The issue is that you couldn't re-assign it to `regions` as it's a `const`

Comment: Yeah there are a lot of cool array functions - MDN documents them pretty well, I'd recommend checking out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [**`Array#some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) as callback and use [**ES6's destructuring assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to concisely get the `isVisible` property to examine and filter out entries, where none of the `isVisible` keys are `true`:

```js
const regions = [
  {
    displayName: 'NYC',
    locations: [
      {name: 'thing', isVisible: false},
      {name: 'thing1', isVisible: false},
      {name: 'thing3', isVisible: false},
    ],
  }, 
  {
    displayName: 'Seattle',
    locations: [
      {name: 'thing', isVisible: true},
      {name: 'thing1', isVisible: true},
      {name: 'thing3', isVisible: true},
    ],  
  },
  {
    displayName: 'Washington',
    locations: [
      {name: 'thing', isVisible: true},
      {name: 'thing1', isVisible: false},
      {name: 'thing3', isVisible: true},
    ],  
  },
];

const filteredRegions = regions
  .filter(region => region.locations
    .some(({isVisible}) => isVisible))

console.log(filteredRegions);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const regions = [{displayName: 'NYC', locations: [{name: 'thing', isVisible: false}, {name: 'thing1', isVisible: false}, {name: 'thing3', isVisible: false},],},]

console.log(regions);

regions.filter(region => {
    !region.locations.filter(location => {
        location.isVisible
      }).length != 0
  });

console.log(regions);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    displayName: 'NYC',
    locations: [
      {name: 'thing', isVisible: false},
      {name: 'thing1', isVisible: false},
      {name: 'thing3', isVisible: false},
    ],
  },
]

[]
```

If you're going to be changing the contents like that, regions probably shouldn't be defined as a const.

Answer (score 1):

```
regions = regions.filter((region) => {
    const locations= region.locations.map((location) => {
        if(location.isVisible) return location;
    });
    if(locations.length === 0) return region;
})
```

You can try this method

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you have todo.

```js
const regions = [
  {
    displayName: 'NYC',
    locations: [
      {name: 'thing', isVisible: false},
      {name: 'thing1', isVisible: false},
      {name: 'thing3', isVisible: false},
    ],
  }, 
  {
    displayName: 'Seattle',
    locations: [
      {name: 'thing', isVisible: true},
      {name: 'thing1', isVisible: true},
      {name: 'thing3', isVisible: true},
    ],
  },
];

function getVisible(someRegions) {
    var regionsWithVisibleLocations = someRegions.filter(function(region) {
        return region.locations.some(function(location) {
            return location.isVisible;  
        });    
    });
    
    return regionsWithVisibleLocations;
}

console.log("result: ", getVisible(regions));
```